# jQuery .click function not work after reload

Tags: javascript, jquery, removeclass

I use jQuery on my website to add a new class and remove the other, but after a reload of the page, the new class disappears.

Code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#list').click(function(event){event.preventDefault();$('.viewgrid').addClass('viewlist');$('.viewgrid').removeClass('viewgrid');});
    $('#grid').click(function(event){event.preventDefault();$('.viewlist').addClass('viewgrid');$('.viewlist').removeClass('viewlist');});
});
```

How do I keep the modification?

Comment: You can use cookies or HTML5 web storage to have information persist across pages for a user.

Comment: If you want the state of the page to be persisted somewhere then you have to persist it somewhere.

Comment: Francesca, welcome. Thank you for providing a code sample but please learn how to format it so it is more readable. I would do it for you but can't access the Edit button on your post right now.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery is a framework for javascript which is running client side within your browser. If you don't save your changes in the file, the changes will only be temporary.

**EDIT:**
You need to load the state on siteload:

```
var def = 'viewlist';
var view = Cookies.get('view') || def;

$('#view').addClass(view);
```

And save it on a click on the button:

```
Cookies.set('view', 'viewlist');
```

I wrote this little codepen for you: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/oBezzz

Notice that I used the JS plugin [JavaScript Cookie](https://github.com/js-cookie/js-cookie). You need to download it and include it into your head section.

Comment: and what's the mode to save the changes in the file ?

Comment: I can use localStorage function ?

Comment: That depends on what you are trying to build. You can use cookies for small pieces of data, or localStorage for more data. The browser then stores this data. If you use another browser, this data cannot be received. If you want the same result in every browser you need to store the data globally on a server.

Comment: can you help me ?

Comment: I must change only small pieces of data so i think that i can use cookies...but what's the mode ? can you help me ?

Comment: What do you mean with "mode"? You have your normal page, on `$(document).ready` you check your cookie and depending on that set or not set a class. Whenever you click the button you toggle that class and update the cookie

Comment: With "mode" i mean: what's the code to insert  to activate cookies ?

Comment: <pre> <code>$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#list').click(function(event){event.preventDefault();$('.viewgrid').addClass('viewlist');$('.viewgrid').removeClass('viewgrid');
 $.cookie('gridcookie', 'list', { expires: 7});
 });
    $('#grid').click(function(event){event.preventDefault();$('.viewlist').addClass('viewgrid');$('.viewlist').removeClass('viewlist');
 $.cookie('gridcookie', 'grid', { expires: 7});
 });
 
});</pre> </code>

Comment: Please see my answer  above. I added some code and linked a codepen which works as desired.

Comment: many many thanks Dennis.. :) but the code not work perfectly.. i mean that i have a grid of 20 products and the code changes only to the first product

Comment: I set an id for the div, so it must be unique. Replace it with a classname of your choice and adjust  the `$('#view')` selector.

Comment: the DIV ID is the same (#view) for all products but change the class of the first only...

Comment: i have included two plugin: <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/js-cookie/js-cookie/master/src/js.cookie.js"></script>

Comment: Yes it changes only the first because ids must be unique. Change the id to a class and select for that one

Comment: Hi Dennis i solved ! I have add the id name view in the class $('.view').removeClass('viewgrid').addClass('viewlist');
        Cookies.set('view', 'viewlist');
    });    so now work very well !! I'm grateful !!

Comment: Help !! the cookie not work now when i reload page ? why ? i haven't change anything..